# Get files from Sharepoint after doing a Filter on Array

Tags: power-automate

The problem I am having is :

1. Sharepoint Get File Files (Properties Only) can only do one filter for ODATA, not a a second AND clause so I need to use Filter Array to make secondary filter work. And it does work....
2. But now I need to take my filtered array and somehow get the {FullPath} property and get the file content via passing a path and I get this error...

[image]
[image]

> [   {
> "@odata.etag": ""1"",
> "ItemInternalId": "120",
> "ID": 120,
> "Modified": "2022-03-21T15:03:31Z",
> "Editor": {
> "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser",
> "Claims": "i:0#.f|membership|dev@email.com",
> "DisplayName": "Bob dole",
> "Email": "dev@email.com",
> "Picture": "https://company.sharepoint.us/sites/devtest/_layouts/15/UserPhoto.aspx?Size=L&AccountName=dev@email.com",
> "Department": "Information Technology",
> "JobTitle": "Senior Applications Developer II"
> },
> "Editor#Claims": "data",
> "Created": "2022-03-21T15:03:31Z",
> "Author": {
> "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser",
> "Claims": "i:0#.f|membership|dev@email.com",
> "DisplayName": "Bob Dole",
> "Email": "dev@email.com",
> "Picture": "https://company.sharepoint.us/sites/devtest/_layouts/15/UserPhoto.aspx?Size=L&AccountName=dev@email.com",
> "Department": "Information Technology",
> "JobTitle": "Senior Applications Developer II"
> },
> "Author#Claims": "i:0#.f|membership|dev@email.com",
> "OData__DisplayName": "",
> "{Identifier}": "Shared%2bDocuments%252fSDS%252fFiles%252fA10_NICKEL%2bVANADIUM%2bPRODUCT_PIS-USA_French.pdf",
> "{IsFolder}": false,
> "{Thumbnail}": ...DATA,
> "{Link}": "https://company.sharepoint.us/sites/devtest/Shared%20Documents/SDS/Files/A10_NICKEL%20VANADIUM%20PRODUCT_PIS-USA_French.pdf",
> "{Name}": "A10_NICKEL VANADIUM PRODUCT_PIS-USA_French",
> "{FilenameWithExtension}": "A10_NICKEL VANADIUM PRODUCT_PIS-USA_French.pdf",
> "{Path}": "Shared Documents/SDS/Files/",
> "{FullPath}": "Shared Documents/SDS/Files/A10_NICKEL VANADIUM PRODUCT_PIS-USA_French.pdf",
> "{IsCheckedOut}": false,
> "{VersionNumber}": "1.0"   } ]

Comment: Can you give us a broken down example of the 'Filter array' results (in JSON, not screenshot)?  It looks to me like you need another loop because the array will be filtered but that may result in more than one results, no?  You go straight from the filter array into the get file content action.

Comment: I added Output JSON for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up doing this and it works.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So from what I can see, I think it's what I thought.  Even though you're filtering an array down to a single element, you need to treat it like an array.

I'm going to make an assumption that you're always going to retrieve a single item as a result of your filter step.

I created a variable (`SharePoint Documents`) to store your "filtered" array so I could then do the work to extract the `{FullPath}` property.

[image: JSON]

I then created variable that is initialised with the **first** (again, I'm making the assumption that your filter will only ever return a single element) and used this expression ...

```
variables('SharePoint Documents')?[0]['{FullPath}']
```

[image: Variable]

This is the result and you can use that in your next step to get the file content from SharePoint ...

[image: Result]

If my assumption is wrong and you can have more than one then you'll need to throw it in a loop and do the same sort of thing ...

[image: Loop]

This is the expression contained within ...

```
items('For_Each_in_Array')['{FullPath}']
```

Result ...

[image: Loop Result]